# What is this error coming from source-map-loader and how do I resolve it?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've created a new react app using create-react-app and am trying to build the files but I am now getting all of these errors. I've been trying to debug this for an hour now, but have made little to no progress. This error is coming from a number of dependencies.

What is this error, and how to I fix it? This is a pretty bare bones project right now, so I'm not entirely sure why this error just popped up.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/react-double-scrollbar/dist/DoubleScrollbar.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/localmachine/Desktop/temp/app/node_modules/react-double-scrollbar/dist/DoubleScrollbar.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/localmachine/Desktop/temp/app/node_modules/react-double-scrollbar/dist/DoubleScrollbar.js.map'
 @ ./node_modules/material-table/dist/material-table.js 42:51-84
 @ ./node_modules/material-table/dist/index.js 29:44-71
 @ ./src/components/countries-data-table/index.js 5:0-43 97:32-45
 @ ./src/App.js 9:0-67 112:39-57
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:38-41
```

Answer (score 7):

Facing the same issue.
So far I have found a workaround given by someone here: https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1030#issuecomment-1004245791

> just add the `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` before the start script in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

good answer here:  [React material-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768587/react-material-table)

you can add the file manually or live with it i guess :(

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue when a package is reinstalled with new version. But restarting sever(ctrl c and npm start) resolved this problem.